# Call FrameworkWiring.refreshBundles() in Activator stop method

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

Exported packages remain imported after I uninstall one of my bundle. I understand this is the right behavior, it is well documented [here](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html). My question is, it is OK to call FrameworkWiring.refreshBundles(mybundle) in the stop method in my bundle's activator or it can cause any problem? I have tested, made many uninstall, install and seems to be OK.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably safe since the actual refresh happens on another thread owned by the framework.